# Running Multi Startup Application does not stop the application on Release but stops them on Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ipc

I have a question on the difference off the Debug and Release build run for Visual Studio 2010. I have a solution that has two project A and B. A depends on B and calls B's method thru interprocess communication IPC.

Here are the scenarios:

```
CASE A:
Run B only 
- Stops the window when you click the STOP button on both on Debug and Release

CASE B:
Multi Startup Run Both A and B (Both action are set to "Start"):
- Irregardless of the order of run, 
  On Release run, A is STOP but B is not stopped 
  On Debug run, B and A are both stopped
```

I am wondering what is the difference when running multi startup on Visual Studio on Debug and Release versions. The odd thing that I can think of is B registers an IPCServiceChannel on Startup. But why the problem is B can stop properly when I just run it by itself.

```
IpcServerChannel serverChannel = new IpcServerChannel("ProcessName");
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, true);
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up for Multi Startup for more than project requires setting up Action for every project

Actions such as  : None, Start & Start without debugging

Also one more important thing is you need set the order in which the project should start

For example if you want your Server to start first but if it is last in the order than it will start last in order. You will have to move the Server project to execute first and then the rest in order

Conclusion : In a multi start up project you must set the action and the order for every project

Comment: Yes, I forgot to that in the question. I already set them both to Start. The problem is not because the process is not starting but because the process is not stopping.

Comment: @Nap check what are difference in your release and debug config, may be that might help